# File Chooser In Gluon Mobile

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon, javafxports

I m using **Gluon 5.0.2**

I am trying to make an app that takes an file url and download it to user specified location

But I cannot make the user to select a directory where to save file

Also all the plugins are added to my `build.gradle` file

I got the follwowing code from Gluon Documentation, and modified it little bit

```
 Services.get(StorageService.class)
      .flatMap(StorageService::getPrivateStorage)
      .ifPresent(c->label.setText("File Directory:  "+c.isDirectory());
```

I supposed that it will show some directory chooser or file chooser like that we have in windows 
but instead it just shows
`File Directory:  true` on the output label

It doesn't ask to choose a directory

How can I show a dialog to the user that allows selecting a directory in android mobiles using gluon mobile?

Comment: I think private storage will only store data in a folder specific to the app. Look into public storage.    https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.3/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/StorageService.html

Comment: You have access to local storage in a sandboxed area provided to your application, or you have access to some public directories, as mentioned by Sedrick. But there is no File/Directory chooser available on Android or iOS. You could create your own dialog to allow the user select a possible public location.

Comment: @Sedrick as you mentioned to use the public storage, I m confused as it needs a directory as a parameter, check here
https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.3/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/StorageService.html

Comment: @JoséPereda how can I make one such dialog. Any demo or something like that..... can you provide me?

Comment: See [dialog](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog.html)'s javadoc. You can place any content. See this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files) to find out about file storage on Android.

Comment: @JoséPereda that's great but I want some code that works directly on android which allows user to choose a directory, may be an android project that implements this feature.... just to get an idea how to make it..... then I will try to replicate that implementation using javafx